# How to access $valid from outside multiple forms

Tags: angularjs, wizard

I've got a form wizard that's comprised of a single form and several sub-forms where each sub-form is a step in the wizard.

In my menu/navigation bar at the top of the page outside of the main form I want to be able to set the CSS class on each step link based on whether the sub-form is $valid or $invalid.

What is a good Angular way to structure this?

Managing a set of steps seems like something that should go in a service. But since the forms are DOM elements then shouldn't the code be in a directive?

Comment: I think it depends on the complexity of your design.  Are the forms on the same page? If so, you can just set the class/style directly in your markup.  If not, how are you caching the form data?

Comment: Single page. The logic for the link CSS class isn't trivial so I want it in code. At the moment it's in a controller. But should it be there if its accessing form elements using jquery.

Comment: Really hard to say without seeing your setup. In the end, though, the form is either $valid or not. So if the css is just triggered by that boolean state, the answer to the menu problem could be as simple as [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/FfBnCllXWLWCuulCwnms?p=preview). But I'm guessing it isn't that simple.

Comment: As for dom lookups - yes a directive is the place to go, updating a single service with your data.

Comment: Trouble with this is that its making redundant copies of the $valid state in the service. They could get out of sync with the real values from the forms. The service needs to be dependent on the directive. Or at least the service needs to be dependent on a '$valid provider' interface that is implemented by a directive.

Comment: I think the reason this awkwardness occurres is that Angular JS has got something wrong. One should be calling $valid on the model and not on the form. i.e. the validation should be defined on the model properties.